# Showing attribute text from selected feature from QComboBox list with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qt

I have a layer that I can edit with a mouse click on features in the map (dialog will open). Attribute fields can be edited via dropdown menu.

How can I display the currently saved value of a feature in the dropdown menu?

I made the Dialog with Qt Designer.

```
    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        self.layer.removeSelection()

        found_features = self.identify(event.x(), event.y(), [self.layer], QgsMapToolIdentify.TopDownAll)
        self.layer.selectByIds([f.mFeature.id() for f in found_features], QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)
        mylayer = self.layer

        #get field index
        loadcategory= mylayer.fields().indexFromName('loadcategory')
        
        seg = mylayer.getSelectedFeatures()

        for j in seg:
            geom = j.geometry()
            
            # show value in fields
```

Here I stuck in following line:

```
            self.dlg.loadcategory.currentText()

            
            # show dialog frame
            self.dlg.show()
           
            result = self.dlg.exec_()   
    
            # See if "save" was pressed
            if result:
                # save process:
                mylayer.startEditing()
            
                self.dlg.loadcategory.itemData(j.setAttribute(loadcategory, self.dlg.loadcategory.currentText()))

                
                mylayer.updateFeature(j)
                mylayer.commitChanges()
                mylayer.removeSelection()
```

How I can I replace `.currentText()` like for QLineEdit with `.setText(j.attributes()[loadcategory])`?

I think it is simple but I didn't found the right method in the documentation for QComboBox class yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by @Benw](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438692/showing-attribute-text-from-selected-feature-from-qcombobox-list-with-pyqgis/438757#comment716160_438692):

> If your combo box is editable, you can just use `setCurrentText()`
> method. To also add it to the drop down list, use `addItem()` method
> first.